# What's the best way to pass an object to an NSViewController on application launch?

Tags: swift, cocoa

In my `AppDelegate`'s `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I need to create an object using data read from disk, and then pass this object to the initial view controller for display. What would be the best way to do this?

Right now I'm loading the storyboard programatically like so:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    importantThing = ImportantThing()
    importantThing.load(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "..."))

    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    myWindowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "MyWindowController") as! NSWindowController
    (myWindowController.contentViewController as? MyViewController)?.importantThing = importantThing
    myWindowController.showWindow(self)
}
```

But this feels clunky. For one, the property is being set after `viewDidLoad`, so now view setup is weird.

There must be a better way to do this. If possible, I would like to not resort to using a singleton, because I actually need to set up a few interconnected objects (two objects with important state that have references to each other, but it doesn't make sense for either to contain the other). What would be a good way to solve this?

Comment: "The property is being set after `viewDidLoad`" I'm no expert, but are you sure about that?

Comment: Yeah, I tried logging the property value in `viewDidLoad` and it's still `nil`

Comment: Tested again to be sure, and sure enough, when I print "viewDidLoad" and "didSet" in their respective functions, "viewDidLoad" appears first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing in the app delegate is correct. As for what you should do in the view controller, Apple's Master-Detail app template shows you the correct pattern (I've added a few comments):

```
// the interface
@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

// the property
var detailItem: NSDate? {
    didSet {
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {
    // check _both_ the property _and_ the interface
    if let detail = self.detailItem { // property set?
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel { // interface exists?
            label.text = detail.description
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // at this point, its _certain_ that the interface exists
    self.configureView()
}
```

If you think about it, you'll see that the interface is updated correctly *regardless of the order of events* — that is, regardless of whether `viewDidLoad` or the setting of the property comes first. Just follow that pattern.

Comment: @ElTomato It's the pattern, not the details. :)

Comment: Alright, looks like it's close enough to what I figured should be done. I thought there might be a better solution I wasn't seeing, but if Apple itself suggests this, I don't see why I shouldn't go with it. Thanks.